# How do I find all known IPs for a given domain in Linux?

Tags: linux, dns, ip-address, amazon-web-services

I am a developer on a project that uses amazon servers for testing. I am switching from using `FoxyProxy` to routing with `iptables` because it is more convenient.

The trouble I ran into is that when running DNS resolution I find that more than one address is returned with multiple calls to resolve a given domain.

For instance:

```
$ host sample.domain.com
sample.domain.com has address 50.200.80.100
$ host sample.domain.com
sample.domain.com has address 50.200.80.101
```

This is a stark contrast to google which:

```
$ host www.google.com
www.google.com has address 74.125.225.81
www.google.com has address 74.125.225.80
www.google.com has address 74.125.225.84
www.google.com has address 74.125.225.82
www.google.com has address 74.125.225.83
www.google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:4009:803::1012
```

Currently I am resolving the host many times to build a list of IPs and use that to set the iptable routes. Is there a better way to do this?

Note: I don't have access to change anything about the server so any suggested solution will have to be client side.

Comment: Can you give a real domain name that causes the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not permitted to provide that information.

Comment: My test here with www.zdf.de showed that nslookup and host both return two IP addresses in one call. If I call the lookups again, I get the same result. So if you don't want to provide **any** DNS name (no need to provide the critical ones) that shows the result you describe I cannot reproduce that here and help you.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the high traffic websites have multiple front-end servers serving the traffic. Mostly each of these IP addresses would be a load balancer, behind which there would be even more number of servers.

If you are interested on getting the *"A"* record for a domain you can use `dig`, `nslookup` or `host` command. If you are using `Linux` then `dig` command would be the preferred way of getting it.

```
$ dig A google.com +short @8.8.8.8
74.125.236.167
74.125.236.160
74.125.236.169
74.125.236.168
74.125.236.161
74.125.236.162
74.125.236.164
74.125.236.163
74.125.236.165
74.125.236.174
74.125.236.166
```

The above command gathers all *"A"* record (Address) of the domain `google.com`. Each time you query it you will get the same set of IP addresses but in a different order.

I am not sure what kind of `iptables` rule you are going to use, but mostly the *"A"* record will belong to the same network like `74.125.236.0/24` based on my `dig` output.

Comment: When I run this command I only get one address: `216.58.216.192`

Comment: Although it looks like this might be because of my company's DNS server. When I run on a personal computer it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no easy way to do this.

If you were able to do a zone transfer of the google.com zone, you could then parse all A and AAA records. However, google does not permit public zone transfers and even if they did, their dns data likely changes frequently.

Google publishes their current network ranges in a dns TXT record. https://support.google.com/a/answer/60764?hl=en

```
$ nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks.google.com 8.8.8.8
$ nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks2.google.com 8.8.8.8
```

You can also use ARIN's WhoIS to search for an IP address or company. http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-74-125-0-0-1/pft

Keep in mind that Network blocks may be registered to ISPs and subsets may be given to a specific organization.